# C++ Functions from Arrays not calling correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, function, math

I am having issues with functions 2, 3, and 4. I think I must have some logic error because my mind cannot wrap around what the issue is. The functions, each time they are called, should perform their arithmatic. For example, each time the *2 function is called, it should multiply the values in the array by two. It does this once, but stays at that value. I need to get it to multiply (in this example) the integers in the array each time. I am very new to C++ and would appreciate any feedback as to what problems would be in these functions.

Here is what I have:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



void initialize (int a[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
}



void times2 (int a[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i*2;
    }
}



void halve (int a[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
    a[i] = i/2;
    }
}



void square(int a[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
    a[i] = i*i;
    }
}


void shiftleft(int a[])
{
    int temp=a[0];
    for (int i=0; i<=8; i++) 
    {
       a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
    a[9]=temp;
}


void shiftright(int a[])
{
    int temp=a[9];
    for (int i=9; i>=0; i--) 
    {
       a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[0]=temp;
}




int main()
{
    int numbers[10];   // a 10 element array of integers, numbers[0]...numbers[9]
    int option;

    initialize(numbers);

    do
    {

        cout << "\nYour array of numbers\n";

        for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
            cout << numbers[i] << " ";

        cout << "\n\nPlease Select and Option \n\n";
        cout << "   1. Initialize\n";
        cout << "   2. Double\n";
        cout << "   3. Halve\n";
        cout << "   4. Square\n";
        cout << "   5. Shift Left\n";
        cout << "   6. Shift Right\n";
        cout << "   or any other number to exit\n";
        cin >> option;

        if (option ==1)
            initialize(numbers);

        else if (option == 2)
            times2(numbers);

        else if (option == 3)
            halve(numbers);

        else if (option == 4)
            square(numbers);

        else if (option == 5)
            shiftleft(numbers);
        else if (option == 6)
            shiftright(numbers);

    }
    while ((option >= 1) && (option <= 6));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `a[i] = i*2;` --> `a[i] = a[i]*2;`?

Comment: What makes you think this `a[i] = i*2;` sets doubles the value of `a[i]` ?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.I had used both a[i ] = a[i*2] as well as a[i] = i*2 incorrectly.

Comment: Watch out for Undefined Behavior when you access an array element that's out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `times2` function to multiply the current array element values by 2, you have to do specifically that: take the current array element value, multiply it by 2 and store it back into the array element

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i] * 2;
}
```

Your current implementation completely ignores existing array element values and just reinitializes each `a[i]` to `i * 2`.

The same problem is present in each of your modifier functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
void times2 (int a[])
{
  for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
  {
     a[i] = a[i]*2;
  }
}

void halve (int a[])
{
  for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i]/2;
  }
}
```

Comment: All you've done is write code, but not explained why is solves the question. This also just provides code for another answer, which was already correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is using the index for your operations instead of the actual value you want to work with. The reason you're not getting the value that you want is because i is the index - it refers to the *position of the array, not the value contained in the array itself*.

Let's say we have an array:

```
a = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
```

This array has 9 values, and as a result, 9 index positions or indices. But as C++ is zero-indexed (i.e. the positions start from 0), the index numbering is:

```
i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

So you would refer to the i-th value of array by entering its index in square brackets. For example, if you wanted to the *value* of the 4th element in your for-loop, when *index* i = 3, you'd get:

```
a[i] = 20
```

So in your case of your times2 function, you're multiplying the *index* and not the *value*. Replace:

```
a[i] = i*2;
```

with

```
a[i] = a[i]*2
```

The same can be said about your other functions.